# .split is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, jquery-migrate

Recently i've updated jQuery / jQuery UI of my php/javascript system with jQGrid free in it's latest version and after implemented the use of jQuery  1.11.3 and jQuery Migrate 1.4.1.

After several bugs fixed got stuck into this (by the way, i've already searched and tried with stackoverflow references of past resolved questions):

```
var formid = $(".FormGrid");
var form = $(formid).attr("id").split("-").pop();
```

**ERROR**:

```
$(...).attr(...).split is not a function
```

Comment: What does `$(formid).attr("id")` evaluate to?

Comment: As @JonUleis mentioned, just use `formid.attr("id").split("-").pop()`

Comment: @JonUleis: It's a jQuery object, and that wouldn't make any difference. jQuery accepts a jQuery object as an argument to the jQuery function.

Comment: Alex: The `.attr("id")` method will return `undefined` when the selector string didn't match any elements.

Comment: `.attr(name)` returns either `String`, or `undefined` (if the attribute not found). In the latter case you would get `TypeError: $(...).attr(...) is undefined`. In the case of `String`, `split` is available unless you have overridden the `String.prototype.split` function. For example, `String.prototype.split = {}` will cause `$(...).attr(...).split is not a function`. Show us the output of `console.log(String.prototype.split)`

Comment: @JonUleis while not best practice, wrapping a jQuery object in `$()` still works fine and will have no noticeable side effects other than minor performance hit of extra function call

Comment: Please check if your HTML has an element with class `FormGrid`.

Comment: @Ruslan Osmanov and 31piy were right! Since i defined and specific condition to check if return is undefined and manage that. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since undefined means in another words "not set" or "empty", setting a condition to check the return type and it is able to handle errors allowing the method to be called only when requirements meet like a string with some text in it.